# Redirect to the home page after few second for wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create a JS for a page auto redirect to the home page when it is loaded.
But how can I make home_url() right? The below one does seem to work Thanks

```
function Redirect() {
    $redirect_to = home_url();
    window.location =  $redirect_to ; 
} 
setTimeout('Redirect()', 4000);
```

Comment: where exactly should it go? and what is `home_url()` supposed to return?

Comment: home_url() this is a wordpress function, right? Just the Home page

Comment: setTimeout expects a function as parameter, not a string

Comment: If I do like this below, it will work. But I want do variable
<code>  window.location =  "https://my-site.com/"; </code>

Comment: `home_url()` is a PHP function, not a JS function. Even if you get working what you have, your website will constantly refresh every 4 seconds and your visitors will never get past your home page.

Comment: I think he is trying to add the redirect code in a separate JS file and reloads the home page of the WordPress website.

Comment: @BlueLi - Can't you use the default `<meta>` HTML tag to redirect to the home page? It would be better than the `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: There is a logout successfully page. User will be redirectied to the page when they are logged out. After they arrived to the page. I want this JS auto redirect back to the home url. without using php function home_url(), How can we achieve the same goal? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a custom template for the page then add the following code after get_footer() function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirect_to = '<?=site_url()?>';
console.log(redirect_to);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location =  redirect_to ;
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi It is not working correctly
The URL returns like this:
mysite.com/thepage/<?=home_url()?>

Comment: Same: result like this: mysite.com/thepage/<?=site_url()?>

Comment: Are you sure you are adding this to a PHP file like a template or in footer.php? The same code is working fine on my local WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but this code should work:

```
<script>
let dest = <?php echo home_url(). ";";?>
setTimeout(() => {
    window.location = dest;
}, 4000)
</script>
```

basically you pass the home_url from php to js then set a timer to set the window.location to it after 4000 ms (4s)  in javascript